# Static Text in CQRS Read Model?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, command, cqrs

We are using CQRS in our distributed architecture. We have a read model, that contains calculated values at present. We would like to add some static text to the view (html page). Ideally this static text will live in a Resource File, to allow for ease of updating and to have it in one central place. The question I have, is should we bind directly from the Resource File to the view (html page) or should the static text be part of the read model itself?

In the case that it should be part of the read model, how would we trigger changes to the read model for the static text when someone makes a change to the Resource File?

Answer (score 1):

Is the static text part of the interface or of the data?

- Interface text is text like labels. It should not be part of a model (but surely of resources in internationalization contexts).
- Static data text is text that is the same in a specific build but has nothing to do with the interface itself. For example you could have a blurb in a side panel that does not change at all. However, in the future you may want to add a *new* panel with a different blurb *coexisting*. In this case it might make sense to move the data in the model.

If you are in doubt, my personal hunch is to use the YAGNI principle and avoid over-designing you application with "what-if" scenarios..

Comment: The text is more like a blurb at the bottom of the html page. Unlikely to change over time but may be updated once every 6 months. So what I am getting from your answer is it should be part of the read model. The text can sit in a Resources File and is used when the read model is generated.